# This and Extend in Java

Tags: java

So I have question from a past quiz. The following code compiles as long as C and D are in the same package

```
class C {
   int i;
}

class D extends C {
   void m() {
       this.i = 3;
   }
}
```

Can someone explain the concepts why this is true or false?

Comment: Why shouldn't this compile? What is your question?

Comment: I'm not sure this needs downvoting, but the question should be made more clear.

Answer (score 5):

It has a **default** *access modifier*.

Access modifiers:

- `public` world level visibility (all classes, everywhere),
- `protected` like default, but also visible to extending classes,
- `default` (you actually don't write any of the three above) - **package level** visibility.
- `private` class level visibility.

Since your field `i` does not have explicitly written *access modifier* it is implied that it has a **default** access mod. and is visible inside the package.

For more information, read [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

---

Regarding `this` keyword - it's just a refenrece to the *current* object.

Since the class of the current object extends the `C`, it has its methods and fields. And since `i` is visible in the entire package, instance of `D` can access it with `this`.

Comment: Only way this answer is better is if you link to the documentation.

Comment: No, `protected` members are also package visible

Comment: in java protected is also package visible, why? i dont know

Comment: @nachokk no idea either ;) But that's how it is...

Comment: `public`: project level visibility -> wrong! No restrictions whatsoever. Even a class that you didn't made can access public methods/fields/classes. And `default` does not inherit... How can this answer have a +3? :S

Comment: @m0skit0 Just some unclear wording is all. Just needs to be revised for clarity.

Comment: @nachokk it's because visibilities remove restrictions when you go up (private < default < protected < public). It's a design decision.

Comment: @crush You mean missing **important** *details*.

Comment: Better now edited, I removed my downvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the classes has default, means package visibility.
For more about visibilities see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Answer (score 0):

Read this: It clearly explains what you are look for:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: You cannot just put a link in your answer. That's no answer :)

Answer (score -1):

This is because the default visibility is package. So all the other classes in the package can see the variable. And since you are extending C , D inherits the variable i.

Comment: No it does not inherit it. It sees it because they're in the same package.

Comment: I understand its in the same package but D is extending C as well so it inherits the variables as well thats why you can do this.<C member variable>. Can you do that without extending the class? PLease explain the downvote

Comment: @m0skit0 I understand people are downgrading your posts but that doesnt mean to go and do it for other people as well. I am also here to learn ans share my knowledge.

Comment: I don't care about people downvoting answers for fun or rage or whatever. I only downvote wrong answers. `default` fields are NOT inherited by child classes. So no, `D` does not inherit `i` from `C` (`C#i`).

Comment: I am confused here. When you mean by inherit, it means D can access all the variables of C without creating an instance of C. Thats what its meant by this.<c varible>. Also you cant even extend the class C outside the package can you?. So as long as they are in the same package B is 'inheriting' C . can you do this.i without extending C?

Comment: *"Also you cant even extend the class C outside the package can you?"* Of course you can. You can do `D extends C` no matter what package D is in as long as `C` is `public` and not declared `final`. *"So as long as they are in the same package B is 'inheriting' C"* Absolutely not. Inheriting is only when you extend a class. *"can you do this.i without extending C?"* Nope.

Answer (score -2):

It is true.

Since you didn't explicitly specify `C#i` visibility, this means it has `default` visibility, which means **only** package visibility. It is different from `protected` in the way that such fields (or methods or classes or whatever) are not inherited, thus `default` visibility is more restrictive than `protected`.

So doing `this.i` in `D` is valid as long as `C` and `D` are in the same package. Otherwise, even if `D extends C`, `C#i` is not visible because it has `default` visibility (which is not inherited).

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for all visibility modifiers and how they work.

Comment: What is `C#i visibility`?

Comment: In Java, when you refer to a member of a class, you write it like that. Thus `C#i` means field `i` in class `C`.

Comment: Explanation for the downvote is welcome. Or are you just raging? ;)

Comment: I thought it was something like that, but it's been awhile since I've seen it referred to in that fashion. Might be a good idea to add that to your answer. Seeing how the OP is obviously very new to Java, I would expect him to be equally lost. Sometimes more is less.

Comment: Nonsense. It is standard Java notation. If the OP doesn't understand it, he can ask himself.

Comment: That elitest "if he doesn't know then he better educate himself" attitude is probably why you are getting down voted by others. Just a thought.

Comment: Don't put words in my mouth I didn't say. I said he can ask himself, I have no problem answering. And I don't care about your votes, just asking for an explanation for the downvote, maybe I said something wrong. But since it is not here, someone is just obviously raging because his answer is wrong. I never heard any of my students complaining about my supposed "attitude". I'm here to help people in what I know. You can keep hunting reputation if that what matters to you. Take care!

Comment: You've now earned a downvote from me. You might try being more humble at SO.

Comment: As I said, I don't care about downvotes out of pure raging. I'm here to help and learn. I don't care about anything that doesn't fit in these 2 categories. So you can do as you wish ;)